# Decrease USB Detection Time in Linux?

Tags: usb

I'm creating a Linux based test rig for a USB device (not storage). Basically i've set it up using udev rules to automatically open a terminal and run a test script as soon as the USB device is plugged in, and this is all working fine.

However, there is about a 1 second lag between plugging the device in and the script running. Obviously not a problem normally, but when testing thousands of USB devices the time can add up fast.

Is there any way to improve to USB detection time?

Comment: you could use a hub and plug in, say, 4 or 8 devices, and they will be detected in parallel. could your script cope?

Comment: Can't really do that since the test requires some external stimulus to the device, and there's only one machine per PC that can provide that.